# How to insert data into table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large excel sheet which I am inserting data by bulk upload.

My problem is date:

date format is like 09/11/2017. I need to insert this data into table.

Any one can suggest me how to do this by conveting in mysql date format?

Comment: convert the date to yyyy/MM/dd format and then insert into table

Comment: show some of your code, how you have done so far

Comment: And next time, PLEASE structure your text yourself. I did this for you, because it was damn near illegible without any punctuation or paragraphs. It's really not that hard.

Comment: $time = strtotime('10-16-2017');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

echo $newformat;

Comment: $date = "14/12/2017";
$your_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));

Answer (score 3):

Use strtotime() on your first date then date('Y-m-d') to convert it back:

```
$dateFromExcel = strtotime('09/11/2017');
$newDateToInsert = date('Y-m-d',$dateFromExcel);
echo $newDateToInsert;
// 2017-11-09
```

if you are using PHP 5.2 or higher 
use

```
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '09/11/2017')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get row first and then use like this.
This is a function to convert date from DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD :

```
function con2mysql($date) {
  $date = explode("-",$date);
  if ($date[0]<=9) { $date[0]="0".$date[0]; }
  if ($date[1]<=9) { $date[1]="0".$date[1]; }
  $date = array($date[2], $date[1], $date[0]);

 return $n_date=implode("-", $date);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpExcel library to uplod exccel file than you can use following line.
It works perfectly for me.

```
PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($exceldate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```